# how do i use mysqli to make a single user login system

Tags: php, mysqli

Alright so i have been looking around for a simple login system and i have looked at many videos and noticed they are all using MYSQL and according to my webhost i need to use MYSQLi so my code is posted below, can someone help me, everytime i press login it just refreshes the page and does nothing

```
<?php


  $error=''; //Variable to Store error message;
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(empty($_POST['user']) || empty($_POST['pass'])){
        $error = "Username or Password is Invalid";
    }
    else
    {
        //Establishing Connection with server by passing server_name, user_id and pass as a patameter
      $host = "198.91.81.8";
      $user = "iishnoii_admin";
      $pass = "password";
      $db = "iishnoii_seclog";

      $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
        //sql query to fetch information of registerd user and finds user match.
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE password='$pass' AND username='$user'");

        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if($rows == 1){
            header("Location: welcome.php"); // Redirecting to other page
        }
        else
        {
            $error = "Username of Password is Invalid";
        }
        mysqli_close($conn); // Closing connection
    }

  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>IIShNoII</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="login-form">
      <form method="post" action="index.php">
        Username: <input type="test" name="username" /> <br /> <br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" /> <br /> <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that this password is not crucial?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You have defined `$error` but you don't use it!

Comment: In addition, you have to learn how to debug your code. For example, you have to check if you have valid SQL statement by trying to `echo` the SQL statement string.

Answer (score 1):

In your form, the names of the fields are `username` and `password`, but when you try to retrieve them in PHP with `$_POST`, you call them `user`and `pass`.